# Can't login when default database is deleted in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have removed the default database. after that I couldn't login with an error indicating the default database was deleted. how do i solve this?

[image: SQL Server error]

Comment: Since it appears that you're using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), although you don't specify this... on the Connect to Server dialog click the Options button, then on the Connection Properties tab type in the name of a database that exists and that you also have access to  (like `master`, `model`, `msdb`, or `temp`) into the `Connect to database` input.

Comment: tempdb  - not temp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `master` or `tempdb` in Connection properties tab > Connect to database field.

[image]